# Validation to allow Ctrl + V for Firefox but restrict V independently

Tags: javascript, validation, firefox

I'm using the following code to limit entry on some inputs to integers only. This works fine in all the browsers I have tested with the exception of Firefox.

In Firefox when you hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> the function returns *false*.

How can I permit the multiple keypress event with Firefox to allow for these actions without allowing <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> through on other browsers?

```
//Validate integers only
function integersonly(myfield, e) { 
    var key;
    var keychar;
    if (window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    } else if (e) {
        key = e.which;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (iscontrolkey(key)) {
        return true;
    } else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function iscontrolkey(key) {
    if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27) ||
            (key == 63232) || (key == 63233) || (key == 63234) || (key == 63235) || (key == 63272)) return true;
}
```

Comment: You can't rely on characters created from a keycode (for example: try to enter numbers from a number pad). Use `oninput` and RegExp instead.

Comment: Is `oninput` something native to Mozilla? Do I need to browser sniff then run separate validation code for Mozilla browsers?

Comment: @QF_Developer - nope, dunno. Why not right-click the text box and select 'Inspect Element'? If you do so you can then select the 'Properties' tab, you can see which properties/methods the element has.

Comment: @QF_Developer Yes, [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is native to _Firefox_ and all other modern browsers. `oninput` is fired on any change to input's value on real time, including dropped values and clipboard actions.